# Alarm manager for Interval Day - I want to cancel past alarms

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

Alarm should repeat from 8 Am to 8pm daily. How to set that alarm should not work on Sunday, and also the past alarm should not work i.e if I open the app directly Wednesday all the alarm from Mon-Tue immediately prompt on the screen

```
int hour[]={8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
```

AlarmManager  alarmManager;

```
  for (int i=0;i<hour.length;i++)
  {
      alarmManager= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

      Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReminderActivity.class);
      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

      PendingIntent  pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, hour[i], intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
      calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
      calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
      calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour[i]);

      Log.d("sdf","dsgd g"+calendar.getTimeInMillis());

      alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your Sunday problem you may just ask if the day of week is not number 7 (java starts counting from 1). So in your alarm manager:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourDate);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
if(dayOfWeek != Calendar.SUNDAY){
 //fire alarm
}else{
 return
}
```

Also for the second question: you should ask if that time is after current time, set the alarm.

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
  calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour[i]);

  Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
```

To check if your time is after current time, just ask `if(calendar.isAfter(today)){//set alarm}`